# The meaning of the conditional nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's the meaning of the `nil` in else part?

```
+ (NSString *)createFile:(NSData *)data suffix:(NSString *)suffix {
  NSString *tmpPath = [self temporaryFilePath:suffix];
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
    return tmpPath;
  } else {
    nil;
  }
  return tmpPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil;` as a statement does nothing: it references a `nil` value, and then doesn't use it. `else { nil; }` is meaningless, and the code as written would be the same without it:

```objectivec
NSString *tmpPath = [self temporaryFilePath:suffix];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
  return tmpPath;
}

return tmpPath;
```

Because in both code paths here the code ends up returning `tmpPath`, this is equivalent to

```objectivec
NSString *tmpPath = [self temporaryFilePath:suffix];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]);
return tmpPath;
```

It seems unlikely that the original author intended to return `tmpPath` unconditionally this way. Instead, it seems the code here likely meant to `return nil;` on failure to create a temporary file:

```objectivec
+ (NSString *)createFile:(NSData *)data suffix:(NSString *)suffix {
  NSString *tmpPath = [self temporaryFilePath:suffix];
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
    return tmpPath;
  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}
```

An alternative way to express this would be

```objectivec
+ (NSString *)createFile:(NSData *)data suffix:(NSString *)suffix {
  NSString *tmpPath = [self temporaryFilePath:suffix];
  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
    tmpPath = nil;
  }
  return tmpPath;
}
```

which returns `tmpPath` unconditionally (but assigns it a `nil` value on failure). The original snippet appears to be halfway between these two versions, either by accident, or because of a merge conflict, or otherwise.

Comment: Great analysis. I fully agree that returning `nil` on file creation failure was the most likely intent. Otherwise the return value is very misleading to the caller.